# Locking in IHostedService

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core

I have `IHostedService` inheritor service, with process some data, and store the last part in a variable.

```
public class MyService : IHostedService 
{
    private DataType lastData;
    public DataType GetLastData()
    {
       return lastData;
    }

    public void ProcessNextPart()
    {
        ...
    } 
}
```

I also have api controller, which use DI to call `MyService`.
Should i use `lock` or some other approach for `lastData` in this case? As I understand, simultaneous reading (from controller) and writing (from service) for that variable is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose for `MyService`? For `IHostedService`, it is used to handling long task or task which is not related with request. What is the reason you need to call `MyService` from controller? What do you want to achieve in MyService as hosted service and what you want to achieve from controller by MyService?

Comment: MyService is not related with request, it makes calculations in background. Client could request the last part of processed data using controller. So the point is multithread using of variable, where that last part is stored.

Comment: if `DataType` is a class, you're pretty much fine without any locking mechanism. If it's a struct then writing it may not be atomic, in which case you should either add a lock or box the value

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on whether `DataType` is a class or a struct.

If it's a class, then writing it is atomic, so it's pretty much safe. If you think the caller could use that value in a loop, then you may want to add a volatile read to prevent the value from being cached in a register:

```
public class MyService : IHostedService 
{
    private DataType lastData;

    public DataType GetLastData()
    {
       return Volatile.Read(ref lastData);
    }

    public void ProcessNextPart()
    {
        lastData = newValue;
    } 
}
```

But given the use-case, that sounds highly unlikely.

If `DataType` is a struct, then it's a whole different story. If the struct is bigger than the target architecture pointer size (4 bytes for x86, 8 bytes for x64), then writing it isn't atomic. Even if the struct is small enough, I don't recommend relying on it since you could add more fields later and break this code. So you have two solutions: either use a lock, or box the value.

Using a lock:

```
public class MyService : IHostedService 
{
    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    private DataType lastData;

    public DataType GetLastData()
    {
       lock (syncRoot)
           return lastData;
    }

    public void ProcessNextPart()
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            lastData = newValue;
    } 
}
```

Boxing the value:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class MyService : IHostedService 
{
    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    private StrongBox<DataType> lastData;

    public DataType GetLastData()
    {
        return lastData.Value;
    }

    public void ProcessNextPart()
    {
        lastData = new StrongBox<DataType>(newValue);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is the first case true for List<T> and nullable (int?, for example) ?

Comment: `List<T>` is a class, so it's the first case. `Nullable<T>` is a struct, so second case